# How to display infowindow and polylines using array of addresses in google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am able to display multiple markers on google map, but my infowindow are not appearing, also not able to display polyline...Can anyone help me with the code, here is my code sample which works for marker but not polyline and infowindow...

I am taking address from table rows and columns...

```
var t= document.getElementById('map_table');

var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(12.97160, 77.59456); 

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_selected'), 
{
    zoom:12,
    center:latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var address = [];
var mark=[];
var info = [];
var pathMap =[];

for(var i=0; i<t.rows.length; i++)
{
    address[i] = t.rows[i+1].cells[2].innerHTML + "," + t.rows[i+1].cells[3].innerHTML;
    var gc = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    gc.geocode({'address': address[i]}, function (res, status)
    {
        mark[i]=new google.maps.Marker({
        position: res[0].geometry.location,
        map: map
    });

    info[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content:address[i]
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(mark[i], 'click', function() {
        info[i].open(map,mark[i]);
    });

    pathMap.push(res[0].geometry.location);

    if (pathMap.length == t.rows.length)
    {
        var routePath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: pathMap, 
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 0.50,
        strokeWeight: 2
    });

    pathMap.setMap(map);
  }});
}
```

Comment: Can you pls check in the firebug and let us know If any eeror message is showing.

Comment: No, I am not getting any error msg...

Answer (score 0):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(mark[i], 'click', function() {
    info[i].open(map,mark[i]);
});
```

`i` is available inside the `for` loop. The loop prints the markers. When someone actually clicks the `mark[i]`, the event is happening outside the loop, so `i` has no value and `info[i]` is no use.

You can do this: specify `title` of a marker.

```
mark[i]=new google.maps.Marker({
    position: res[0].geometry.location,
    map: map,
    title: i
});
```

Catch the title in the `click` event and display appropriate info.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(mark[i], 'click', function( e ) {
    info[ e.title ].open(map, e);
});
```

I haven't tested the last bit of code, you need to experiment with the event target.